# Angular 4 apply conditional validation only if field is touched / dirty - AbstractControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add conditional email validation **only** to a Reactiveforms Angular 4 form. Validation should only get applied when a user starts to fill out the email field. If the email field is empty, no validation should be applied.

I currently have the following set up and using `AbstractControl`, though not sure I'm going about this the right way.

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
  // build the form
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    customer: this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [ this.checkEmail ] ],
      checkboxEmail: false
    })
  })
}

// custom validator
checkEmail(control: AbstractControl){
    if(control.touched && control.dirty) {
      return Validators.email
    } else if (control.value === '') {
      return null
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now thinking about it with - would it be better to check if the field was populated by the following. And then check if it's empty.

```
 this.form.get('customer.email').valueChanges.subscribe(

  (email: string) => {
    // logs on every change (in this case a keystroke)
    console.log('email field changing');

    if (email.value !== '') {
      // apply validation.email
    }
 })
```

**UPDATE**

I scraped the above and went with the below which only half works

```
 checkEmail(control: AbstractControl){

   if(control.dirty && control.value !== '') {
     control.setValidators([Validators.email]);
   } 
 }
```

The above initially sets the field as valid and only applies the email validation when there is content. However it does this **only** after a second key stroke. `aa`

**Also** when the field is cleared out - the validation still applies (i want the email validator to not be applied if the field is blank)

Comment: Are you trying to show the validation errors on dirty checking ?

Comment: @Abrar well I want to eventually display a message to the user, so i don't want this message appearing before they even touch the field (hence `touched`) perhaps i don't need the dirty checking. But more that the user has typed .. I've add some code in above with this in mind.

Comment: I didn't understood your issue clearly, I know that its about the Form Validations in angular 4, So why dont you check out this [doc](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#component-class).

Comment: @SjVnyk I want to apply email validation. But only if the field has content inside it. If the field it empty then no validation should be applied.

Comment: Well, there are 2 open pull requests (yes, 2) [**#16902**](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/16902) and [**#16276**](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/16276) to disable the behavior that if the *email* is blank it shouldn't be validated. While it's not merged, I'd recommend you to use `Validators.pattern(any email regex that you can easily find anywhere)`.